# Why does AdmZip fail to zip throwing range error for a folder with size 525688 bytes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, adm-zip

Edit: I think this is due to my vm running out of space. Also curious, when adm-zip writes into a new zip doesn't it remove the files from the local directory(soruce) and write them into Zip folder (destination) ?

I'm trying to zip a folder using [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) and running into the following error. Is this a known bug ? Or Am I doing something dumb ?

```
INFO    started zipping from source: /tmp/unzippedBuild/lambda to destination: /tmp/postBuild.zip

ERROR   RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 65535. Received 92171
    at checkInt (internal/buffer.js:35:11)
    at writeU_Int16LE (internal/buffer.js:539:3)
    at Buffer.writeUInt16LE (internal/buffer.js:547:10)
    at Object.toBinary (/var/task/node_modules/adm-zip/headers/mainHeader.js:73:15)
    at Object.compressToBuffer (/var/task/node_modules/adm-zip/zipFile.js:305:24)
    at Object.writeZip (/var/task/node_modules/adm-zip/adm-zip.js:618:23)
    at Object.exports.makeZip (/var/task/utils/zipHelper.js:20:13)
    at Runtime.exports.buildHandler [as handler] (/var/task/index.js:31:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My code looks like this:

```
exports.makeZip = function(source, destination) {
    console.info("started zipping from source: %s to destination: %s", source, destination);
    try {
        const zip = new AdmZip();
        zip.addLocalFolder(source);
        zip.writeZip(destination);
        console.info("done zipping");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.stack)
        console.error("Zipping failed. Reason: %s", error)
        throw new Error(error.message)
    }
};
```

du command gives the following size.

```
525688  /tmp/unzippedBuild/lambda
```

Comment: Same issue for me using `adm-zip`. It seems to occur when what I'm zipping is very large. 

 `RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received -6324224`

My trace looks just like yours except for `Object.toBinary` where I instead have: `at Object.dataHeaderToBinary (./node_modules/adm-zip/headers/entryHeader.js:204:18)`

Comment: any solution for this?